# The solutionClass (class Solution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner, timefold

I want to have multiple solution classes and multiple constraint providers, So instead of using @PlanningSolution used solverConfigs(xml). while creating SolverFactory.create() I am getting this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class Solution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.

My ultimate goal is to use multiple solution classes in a single application.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate SolverConfig (or solverConfig.xml) for each one. For example:

```
SolverConfig sc1 = new SolverConfig()
      .withSolutionClass(Sol1.class)
      .with...;
SolverConfig sc2 = new SolverConfig()
      .withSolutionClass(Sol2.class)
      .with...;
```

Then create a seperate `SolverManager` for each one. Both `Sol1` and `Sol2` need a `@PlanningSolution` annotation.

This is already possible in [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)/OptaPlanner today. The Quarkus and Spring Boot integration can't deal with this currently. Feel free to open an issue on Timefold to support this through `@Named` etc.